# How to bring focus to window by process name?

Tags: powershell

If I'm understanding this correctly this code should capture the active window and keep it in focus. `concentr.exe` is the process name.

How do I bring a window in focus based on process name?

```
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class UserWindows {
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
"@            
try {            
    $ActiveHandle = [UserWindows]::GetForegroundWindow()
    $Process = Get-Process | ? {$_.MainWindowHandle -eq $activeHandle}            
    $Process | Select ProcessName, @{Name="concentr.exe";Expression=    {($_.MainWindowTitle)}}            
} catch {            
    Write-Error "Failed to get active Window details. More Info: $_"            
}
```

I've also tried

```
param([string] $proc="Citrix Connection Manager", [string]$adm)
cls

Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class WinAp {
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
}

 "@
  $p = Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle }|where {$_.Name -like   "$proc"}

 if (($p -eq $null) -and ($adm -ne ""))
 {
     Start-Process "$proc" -Verb runAs
 }
 elseif (($p -eq $null) -and ($adm -eq ""))
 {
     Start-Process "$proc" #-Verb runAs
 }
 else
 {
     $h = $p.MainWindowHandle

     [void] [WinAp]::SetForegroundWindow($h)
     [void] [WinAp]::ShowWindow($h,3);
 }
```

Comment: `GetForegroundWindow()` obtains a handle to the current foreground windows, it doesn't *do* anything to it

Comment: Ok so if the process I want to put focus on is concentr.exe how would I do that

Answer (score 15):

I found it:

```
Param(
    [string] $proc="C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\concentr.exe",
    [string] $adm
)
Clear-Host

Add-Type @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public class WinAp {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    }
"@
$p = Get-Process | Where {$_.mainWindowTitle} |
    Where {$_.Name -like "$proc"}
if (($p -eq $null) -and ($adm -ne "")) {
    Start-Process "$proc" -Verb runAs
} elseif (($p -eq $null) -and ($adm -eq "")) {
    Start-Process "$proc"
} else {
    $h = $p.MainWindowHandle
    [void] [WinAp]::SetForegroundWindow($h)
    [void] [WinAp]::ShowWindow($h, 3)
}
```

Answer (score 15):

<sup>Note:

• This answer in part uses the same technique as the existing answers, but also introduces a new technique, and aims to contrast the approaches in a focused manner.

• Only the last solution below - which requires on-demand compilation of C# code via `Add-Member` - properly activates a window if it happens to be *minimized*.

• All solutions use PSv4+ syntax.</sup>

---

**Important**:

- **Unless your code runs in the *current foreground window***, **Windows *prevents* the programmatic activation of other process' windows *by default***: Instead of *activating* the target window, its *taskbar icon flashes*.
- **Enabling *unconditional* programmatic activation requires additional work**, via a per-session P/Invoke call - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73675531/45375).

---

A simpler **solution that doesn't require `Add-Type` with WinAPI P/Invoke signatures** is possible, based on the **`WScript.Shell` COM object's `.AppActivate()` method** (which [Inventologist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608116/45375) hints at):

**Note**:

- If the target window happens to be *minimized*, this solution does put the *focus* on it, but doesn't *restore* it.
- The gist of the solution is the following, using `Notepad` as an example process name; the statement activates the (first) process by that name that has a non-empty window title (if you can assume that the target process always has a window title and can therefore be presumed to be visible, you can simplify to `(Get-Process Notepad)[0].Id`):

  ```
  $null = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate(
    (Get-Process Notepad).Where({ $_.MainWindowTitle }, 'First').Id
  )
  ```

```
function Show-Window {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $ProcessName
  )

  # As a courtesy, strip '.exe' from the name, if present.
  $ProcessName = $ProcessName -replace '\.exe$'

  # Get the ID of the first instance of a process with the given name
  # that has a non-empty window title.
  # NOTE: If multiple instances have visible windows, it is undefined
  #       which one is returned.
  $procId = (Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore $ProcessName).Where({ $_.MainWindowTitle }, 'First').Id

  if (-not $procId) { Throw "No $ProcessName process with a non-empty window title found." }

  # Note: 
  #  * This can still fail, because the window could have been closed since
  #    the title was obtained.
  #  * If the target window is currently minimized, it gets the *focus*, but is
  #    *not restored*.
  #  * The return value is $true only if the window still existed and was *not
  #    minimized*; this means that returning $false can mean EITHER that the
  #    window doesn't exist OR that it just happened to be minimized.
  $null = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate($procId)

}

# Sample invocation
Show-Window notepad
```

---

**A solution that also restores the target window if it happens to be minimized** requires **`Add-Type` with WinAPI P/Invoke declarations**:

**Note**:

- On first invocation of the function in a PowerShell session, there is a noticeable delay due to having to compile the helper type that provides WinAPI access.
- Unlike the solution above, this solution *restores* a currently minimized window to ensure that its content is visible, while properly activating a currently-maximized window without restoring it.

```
function Show-Window {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $ProcessName
  )

  # As a courtesy, strip '.exe' from the name, if present.
  $ProcessName = $ProcessName -replace '\.exe$'

  # Get the PID of the first instance of a process with the given name
  # that has a non-empty window title.
  # NOTE: If multiple instances have visible windows, it is undefined
  #       which one is returned.
  $hWnd = (Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore $ProcessName).Where({ $_.MainWindowTitle }, 'First').MainWindowHandle

  if (-not $hWnd) { Throw "No $ProcessName process with a non-empty window title found." }

  $type = Add-Type -PassThru -NameSpace Util -Name SetFgWin -MemberDefinition @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);    
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);    // Is the window minimized?
'@ 

  # Note: 
  #  * This can still fail, because the window could have been closed since
  #    the title was obtained.
  #  * If the target window is currently minimized, it gets the *focus*, but its
  #    *not restored*.
  $null = $type::SetForegroundWindow($hWnd)
  # If the window is minimized, restore it.
  # Note: We don't call ShowWindow() *unconditionally*, because doing so would
  #       restore a currently *maximized* window instead of activating it in its current state.
  if ($type::IsIconic($hwnd)) {
    $type::ShowWindow($hwnd, 9) # SW_RESTORE
  }

}

# Sample invocation
Show-Window notepad
```

Comment: question how to activate window by process name I accepted something small like `$WSH.AppActivate("title_of_app");` the answer were to long for me as web developer to understand or write in PowerShell that was my point

Comment: @MahmoudMagdy, if the limitations of the first solution are acceptable, here's a single expression (which obviously doesn't include error handling) using `Notepad` as an example: `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((Get-Process Notepad).Where({ $_.MainWindowTitle }, 'First').Id)`. I've also added it to the answer. If you don't need to check for an empty window title: `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((Get-Process Notepad)[0].Id)` By contrast, the more complete second solution has no similarly concise formulation.

Answer (score 12):

Have you thought of using the Window Name?
I've found this bit of code to work great and not take up a lot of space:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$wshell.AppActivate('New Tab - Google Chrome')
```

Also, if you need to just Alt-TAB back to the last thing that ran (ie: you need focus to come back to the script window after firing something off) try this:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$wshell.SendKeys('%{TAB}')
```

Comment: Alt-Tab was what I needed but I had to do it this way `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` and
`[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{TAB}')`

Comment: This proves far less reliable for me, often returning `False`. @user770022 's answer is more reliable. Neither however address input focus

Comment: how you select different than chrome I need use app on my computer, the answer should include how you get the title of the app example super mario game window

Answer (score 3):

I use this script to do this.  Modify as you need...

For example, the default variables `$ProcessNameRegEx` and `$WindowTitleRegEx` will move new Notepad windows (just start a couple of them with no file specifed).

You can pass different regex expressions to the script.  Edit as makes sense to your needs.

**Show-WindowByName**

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string]
    $ProcessNameRegEx = 'notepad',

    [string]
    $WindowTitleRegEx = 'unt'
)

$cs = @" 
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace User32
{
    public static class WindowManagement
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

        public const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x01, SWP_NOMOVE = 0x02, SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40, SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x80;

        public static void SetWindowPosWrappoer(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            if (handle != null)
            { 
                SetWindowPos(handle, 0, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_HIDEWINDOW);

                if (width > -1 && height > -1)
                    SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOMOVE);

                SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShowWindow")]
        public static extern IntPtr ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        public static void ShowWindowWrapper(IntPtr handle, int nCmdShow)
        {
            if (handle != null)
            { 
                ShowWindow(handle, nCmdShow);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetForegroundWindow")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public static void SetForegroundWindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
        {
            if (handle != null)
            { 
                SetForegroundWindow(handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
"@ 

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cs -Language CSharp -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


function Move-Window
{
    param (
        [int]$MainWindowHandle,
        [int]$PosX,
        [int]$PosY,
        [int]$Height,
        [int]$Width
    )

    if($MainWindowHandle -ne [System.IntPtr]::Zero)
    {
        [User32.WindowManagement]::SetWindowPosWrappoer($MainWindowHandle, $PosX, $PosY, $Width, $Height);
    }
    else
    {
      throw "Couldn't find the MainWindowHandle, aborting (your process should be still alive)"
    }
}


function Show-Window
{
    param (
        [int]$MainWindowHandle,
        [int]$CmdShow
    )

    if($MainWindowHandle -ne [System.IntPtr]::Zero)
    {
        [User32.WindowManagement]::ShowWindowWrapper($MainWindowHandle, $CmdShow);
        [User32.WindowManagement]::SetForegroundWindowWrapper($MainWindowHandle);
    }
    else
    {
      throw "Couldn't find the MainWindowHandle, aborting (your process should be still alive)"
    }
}


$windows = Get-Process | ? {$_.ProcessName -match $ProcessNameRegEx -and $_.MainWindowTitle -match $WindowTitleRegEx} | Select -Last 100 | Select Id, MainWindowTitle, MainWindowHandle | Sort MainWindowTitle

$h = 180
$w = 1500
$x = 400
$y = 800
$deltax = 80
$deltay = 180

foreach ($window in $windows)
{
    Move-Window $window.MainWindowHandle $x $y $h $w
    Show-Window $window.MainWindowHandle 5
    #$x -= $deltax
    $y -= $deltay
}
```

Comment: Hmm I havent been able to get this to work. I assume the only change I need to make is 

param (
    [string]
    $ProcessNameRegEx = 'concentr.exe',

    [string]
    $WindowTitleRegEx = 'Citrix Connection Manager'

Comment: I am going to guess the '.' in your input was interpreted not as you expected since this is a regex.

Comment: @KoryGill This won't work as written. The variables called are not used in the code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this @Bewc?  Also, I updated the sample code to work on 2 new notepad windows (with Untitled as the window title).  Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: @KoryGill that was fast! It works for me now. Appreciate the responsiveness!