# Set console Top-Most in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, console, topmost

So while there is much advise about how to set **forms** topmost, i couldnt find anything that makes my console run topmost.

So my question: How do I make my console run top-most during a script?

Comment: See this and my answer and you can modify it to do topmost. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566799/how-to-bring-focus-to-window-by-process-name

Comment: I can't run as admin, unfortunately... :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires some .NET interop, as detailed in this blog:

[Scripts From TechEd 2012… Part 1 (Keeping PowerShell Window On Top)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylorb/2012/06/12/scripts-from-teched-2012-part-1-keeping-powershell-window-on-top/)

I've copied the relevant code below in case the linked site disappears:

```
$signature = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
    int X,
    int Y,
    int cx,
    int cy,
    uint uFlags);
'@

$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name SetWindowPosition -Namespace SetWindowPos -Using System.Text -PassThru

$handle = (Get-Process -id $Global:PID).MainWindowHandle
$alwaysOnTop = New-Object -TypeName System.IntPtr -ArgumentList (-1)
$type::SetWindowPos($handle, $alwaysOnTop, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0003)
```

**Edit:**

As described in the comments:  If you're from a batch file, PowerShell runs in a child process and doesn't own the console window, so you'll have to make changes:

```
$signature = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
    int X,
    int Y,
    int cx,
    int cy,
    uint uFlags);
'@

$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name SetWindowPosition -Namespace SetWindowPos -Using System.Text -PassThru

$handle = $type::GetConsoleWindow()
$type::SetWindowPos($handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0003)
```

Comment: Nice. From what I can tell, you can just pass `-1` directly as `hwndInsertAfter` (or use `[IntPtr] -1` for clarity) - no need for `New-Object`.

Comment: Okay this works fine in the console. But I want this to work in a script =) this gives me an error which seems to result from the `'@ @'`?
I have no clue about .NET yet so sry if my analesys ist too good =)

Comment: @mklement0 So I can remove the `$alwaysonTop ...` and replace `IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,` with `[IntPtr] -1`?

Comment: @Omglolyes: You can replace `$type::SetWindowPos($handle, $alwaysOnTop, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0003)` with `$type::SetWindowPos($handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0003)`

Comment: @Omglolyes: The closing delimiter of a here-string - `'@` in this case - must be not only on its own line, but must also be _at the very start of the line_ - not even whitespace may precede it.

Comment: AAAAHHH Okay so I can't even tab into my code. Fine but this somehow didn't do the trick for me. I dont get an error anymore, but even if I put this at the start of my script, it does'nt seem to do anything anymore.
It also gives me a "false" instead of "true" like in the normal console.

Comment: How are you executing the script?

Comment: Well Powershell is kindof resticted at work. So I run a batchcommand:

`PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command ". '%cd%\a.ps1'; Test;"`

Comment: @boxdog, your script has [curly quotes](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html) that [aren't well supported](https://4sysops.com/archives/dealing-with-smart-quotes-in-powershell/) in Powershell.

Comment: @Omglolyes: If you're from a batch file, PowerShell runs in a child process and doesn't own the console window, so you'll have to make changes: Add `[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();` to the value of `$signature`, replace the `$handle = ...` line with `$handle = $type::GetConsoleWindow()`

Comment: @RichMoss: It's definitely better to avoid the non-ASCII-range quotation marks, but do note that PowerShell _itself_ fully supports them. The problem is usually one of _character encoding_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/45375).

Comment: @RichMoss.  As I said in the post, I literally copy/pasted it from a blog, so that's where the odd quotes come from.  Having said that, I should have checked it, rather than just assuming it was OK. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks alot. This works entirely. This will save me much time and some nerves. 
@boxdog