# Is there a way to switch to or focus a specific UWP app from powershell

Tags: powershell, uwp

I would like to use a powershell script to focus/switch to a UWP (Windows app store style app) that is currently running.

I use powershell to focus a regular windows application by its process name just fine using a technique found here: [How to bring focus to window by process name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566799/how-to-bring-focus-to-window-by-process-name)

The problem I have using this technique with a UWP app is that UWP apps appear to have 0 as the MainWindowHandle property which tells me its hidden and managed by the system.

Comment: It can propably be done using UI Automation .NET API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview

Comment: PowerShell sample: https://gist.github.com/xiongjia/6749035 (Note that the top-level window of UWP apps is managed by a different process than the app, so you have to search the child windows as well).